# .htaccess different RewriteRule for child of directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite

In my shop i have the problem, that SSL doesn´t work. So i used RewriteRule for force running SSL, but the problem is the admin area doesn´t work like that.(unknown resources load from ...)
For this reason i have to disable this RewriteRule all time if i would change something in the admin area.
It exist a possibility to except the admin area from RewriteRule ?

```
RewriteBase /shop/
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ 
RewriteRule (.*) https://domain/shop/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In the admin area i get with:
http://domain/shop/admin/..

I tried something like that after the Rule above but it doesn´t work:

```
RewriteBase /shop/admin/
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ 
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain/shop/admin/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `/shop/.htaccess` use these 2 rules at the top:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shop/

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/admin/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /admin/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```